# How is the Researchgate (RG) Score calculated? Why does it change over time?

Tags: publications, research-process

While using Researchgate platform for a while, I could not understand how the change of the RG score is carried out. For example, after my first paper RG=1. Afterwards, it became 0.99. Then, after the second paper, RG=1.13. Few days after it became 1.12.

Do you have any idea how this change is carried out? What is the issue behind the score decrease?

Comment: https://explore.researchgate.net/display/support/RG+Score

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: From July 2022, ResearchGate will remove the RG score. They put out an [announcement](https://www.researchgate.net/researchgate-updates/removing-the-rg-score) in which they give their motivation for doing so, which shares many of the arguments from the critical article I cite below.

---

While ResearchGate provides some rough hints on their support pages (see @GoodDeeds's comment), the details of how the RG score is computed are not publicly disclosed.

Relevant article from the London School of Economic's Impact Blog: [The ResearchGate Score: a good example of a bad metric](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2015/12/09/the-researchgate-score-a-good-example-of-a-bad-metric/)

> One of the most apparent issues of the RG Score is that it is in-transparent. ResearchGate does present its users with a breakdown of the individual parts of the score, i.e., publications, questions, answers, followers (also shown as a pie-chart), and to what extent these parts contribute to your score. Unfortunately, that is not enough information to reproduce one’s own score. For that you would need to know the exact measures being used as well as the algorithm used for calculating the score. These elements are, however, unknown.
>
> ResearchGate thus creates a sort of black-box evaluation machine that keeps researchers guessing, which actions are taken into account when their reputation is measured. This is exemplified by the many questions in ResearchGate’s own question and answering system pertaining to the exact calculation of the RG Score. There is a prevalent view in the bibliometrics community that transparency and openness are important features of any metric. One of the principles of the Leiden Manifesto states for example: “Keep data collection and analytical processes open, transparent and simple”, and it continues: “Recent commercial entrants should be held to the same standards; no one should accept a black-box evaluation machine.” Transparency is the only way measures can be put into context and the only way biases – which are inherent in all socially created metrics – can be uncovered.

Answer (score 3):

It is a mysterious metric. When I looked into it at some point, it seemed that for most researchers (i.e., those that either don't use research gate or simply use it to store copies of their articles), it was roughly as follows:

Something like a log (or similar transformation) of the sum of the research gate calculated impact factors of your published journal articles.

The general logic is clear:

- Research gate has its own version of impact factor for each journal based on its own citation database. This is presumably highly correlated with similar  journal metrics that estimate average citations per article in a journal over 2/3/4/5 year period (e.g., Web Of Science impact factor; Scopus Cite Score, etc)
- Thus, each time a researcher gets a publication, the "impact factor" gets added to the total impact factor of their publications.
- However, the raw sum of impact factors would lead to a highly skewed distribution. E.g., someone with one paper in a low impact factor journal might have a score of 1, but a prolific researcher with hundreds of papers in high impact journals might have a score in the thousands. Instead, research gate scores tended to range from 0 to about 60 or 70 or something. So, there was some kind of order-preserving transformation going on (e.g., something like a log).

Assuming the above is all correct **what would cause scores to fluctuate?** First, if you published a new journal article, then your score would go up. The higher the research gate impact factor of the journal, the more your score would go up. Also, because of the transformation, scores rise more rapidly at the low end of the scale. Second, if the journals you published in rose or fell in calculated impact, then your score would also fluctuate. Presumably, over time, if you have a lot of publications in a lot of different journals, this variation could be quite subtle.

**Is this a good metric?**
Assuming the above stated understanding of the metric is correct, is it a good metric?

In general, it should correlate quite highly with h-index in the sense that (a) it is a measure of career-level research output rather than a measure of annual productivity, and (b) it also has the built in log-style scaling of total output whereby each additional increase takes progressively more output.

That said, it is more immediate than h-index and other metrics based on  citations to a researchers articles. Citation-based metrics such as h-index and total citations measure citation impact, which also simply increase with the passage of time since publication. The sum of impact factors is more likely to align with annual researcher citations as the sum of the impact factors is roughly equivalent to sum of expected citations per year (albeit over longer periods of time articles can enter the citation decline phase, and this would no longer hold).

I'm also not sure how it dealt with research output that lacks a research gate impact factor (e.g., books, book chapters).

In focussing on the impact factor of the journals, it does not reward researchers who write highly cited works that in some sense out-perform (from a citation perspective) the journals that they appear in.

Both h-index and sum of impact factors ignore various confounds including (a)   articles with fewer authors are not weighted more in the metric, (b) authorial position (e.g., first, second, last) is not incorporated into the metric, and (c) discipline variation in citation practices is not considered.

And finally, there is the standard critique of all citation based metrics. I.e., quality and importance are not equivalent to article or journal-level metrics of citations.

Of specific relevance to Research Gate Score, they also appeared to have a bunch of other ways of increasing the metric (e.g., by answering questions on the site and so on). These are irrelevant and just add noise from the perspective of evaluating a researcher's career research output.